# Mac gcc compiler does not recognise c11

Tags: gcc

I am trying to run this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
     hello();
 }

 void hello(){
     printf("Hello");
 }
```

using

```
gcc -std=gnu11  main.c
```

without success in Mac. I get

```
 error: implicit declaration of function 'hello' is invalid in C99
```

This is my gcc version

```
% gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Could you help me to understand what is happening here please?

Answer (score 0):

`error: implicit declaration of function 'hello' is invalid in C99`

Either declare or define a function before calling it, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 void hello(){
     printf("Hello");
 }

 int main(){
     hello();
 }
```

EDIT: despite the diagnostic stating C99 (I never bothered with but maybe it's a minor bug?) C11 support can be checked by inspecting `__STDC_VERSION__` macro, which should be set to `201112L`.
This can be checked like that:

```c
#if (__STDC_VERSION__<201112L)
#error C11 support needed
#endif
```

or (if `_Static_assert` is available)

```c
_Static_assert(__STDC_VERSION__>=201112L, "C11 or higher needed");
```

Comment: But I am trying to use c11 a not c99. If you see the error it says "is invalid in C99"

Comment: @Juan think of it as "C99 and onwards" ;) More seriously: that's just the message, maybe an improper one when it comes to way it looks exactly (not sure though), but all in all the behaviour is correct and does not indicate C11 is not supported.